# Get Index of an Item in a List of Class Items with Timer Member

Tags: c#, class, indexof, system.timers.timer

I am trying to find the index of the Triggered Timer.

I created a list of Class Entry here in Program.cs

```
static public List<Entry> Table = new List<Entry>();
```

This is the class called "Entry" with its constructors in Entry.cs

```
public class Entry
    {
        public int pktID;

        public Timer pktTimer= new Timer();
    }


public Entry()
      {
      }




public Entry(int _pktID, Boolean idleTimeOutStart)
        {
            this.pktID = _pktID;

            if (idleTimeOutStart == true)
            {
                pktTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => CallDeleteEntry(sender, e, Program.Table.IndexOf());

                pktTimer.Interval = 10000; // 10000 ms is 10 seconds
                pktTimer.Start();

            }


        }

static void CallDeleteEntry(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, int pktIndex)
        {
            Program.Table.RemoveAt(pktIndex); //Removes Entry at this Index
            Program.Table[pktIndex].idleTimeOutTimer.Stop(); //Stops idleTimeOutTimer of This Entry
        }
```

The items in the list are created randomly. Now each Timer in the List (List Index) will start and then after 10000 msecs, CallDeleteEntry shall be called.

What I need to do is the pass the Index of the Timer when it elapses 10000msec to CallDeleteEntry, so it can remove that item row for the list.

I think something must be modified here to make it work.

```
idleTimeOutTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => CallDeleteEntry(sender, e, Program.Table.IndexOf());
```

The List will look like this

## ListIndex | Entry Item

### 0     |  pkt | pktTimer

### 1     |  pkt | pktTimer

### 2     |  pkt | pktTimer

### 3     |  pkt | pktTimer

### 4     |  pkt | pktTimer

Comment: Where is `idleTimeOutTimer` defined? Your code only defines `PktTimer`.

Comment: my mistake. The idleTimeOutTimer is the pktTimer. I just swapped the names while witting the code here. Thank you for notifying me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pretty close IndexOf requires the item you're trying to get the index of. in this case the Entry class you're trying to get the index of. I believe in your case it would be the key word this, so IndexOf(this).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have decreased the Timer time to 1 second for testing purposes. And after adding the Entry Item to the list. After 1 second it calls CallDeleteEntry and throws an Error. The error is System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.' I debugged it and pktIndex is -1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

@Jason Mastnick

What caused the above error I mentioned in my comments to you was

```
            Program.Table.RemoveAt(pktIndex); //Removes Entry at this Index
            Program.Table[pktIndex].idleTimeOutTimer.Stop(); //Stops idleTimeOutTimer of This Entry
```

I should stop the timer first, then remove the packet

```
            Program.Table[pktIndex].idleTimeOutTimer.Stop(); //Stops idleTimeOutTimer of This Entry
            Program.Table.RemoveAt(pktIndex); //Removes Entry at this Index
```

By the way, your solution works. I should write it like this.

```
pktTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => CallDeleteEntry(sender, e, Program.Table.IndexOf(this));
```

However, a problem occurs. I tried adding the Entries in the List sequentially. The first pktIndex passed is "1" not "0". Since the first item is added at Index 0. It should be the one to be removed first in this sequential scenario. Everything Works well, expect that this first item at Index 0 is not removed. Any ideas?